# OVER_QUERY_LIMIT when using google map API in Google Docs spreadsheet

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a Google docs spreadsheet with some maps api calls as follows:

`=NOEXPAND(importXML("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin="&$A2&"&destination="&I$1&"&sensor=false";"/DirectionsResponse/route/leg/duration/text|/DirectionsResponse/route/leg/distance/text" ))`

I have ten of these formulas in my spreadsheet. (I used to have more, but I took some out because I read somewhere the limit per second was 10).

It was working fine yesterday and this morning, but now I'm getting an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error. I'm not making more than 25,000 calls a day, not even close. And not I'm not making more than 10 per second.

Any ideas why this stopped working???

Could it be something with it being on google docs and other people using the api in there documents it all counts as coming from the same location?

Comment: Interestingly enough, now ONE of the TEN formulas work, and the rest still do not.

Comment: Even more odd, if change one of the addresses for the directions, they all work. If I then change it back to the old address, they stop working again. What is going on?

Comment: Perhaps Google changed the way they enforce the quota or the rate limit.  Last I looked at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#Limits) it said `The Directions API may only be used in conjunction with displaying results on a Google map; using Directions data without displaying a map for which directions data was requested is prohibited` It doesn't sound like you are complying with that restriction.

Comment: Interesting. I have had spreadsheets that have done this for a long time, they are just for my personal use. Interesting to think that to comply I have to display additional information on my own spreadsheet...